# A* with reopening when heuristics is only admissible but not consistent

Tags: artificial-intelligence, shortest-path, a-star

The A* pseudocode I follow is given here:
[image]

My question is: How are we sure that we can return when a goal state is found? As it is with all other CLOSED states, they could be reopened from new OPEN states. So, if I have a state that I got from OPEN and I see that I can take a better path to the CLOSED goal from that state, then I should update its value at least. Shouldn't we wait till all the states are closed?

Answer (score 3):

This works because:

- Heuristics are still admissible, meaning that the heuristic cost `h(n)` of a node `n` must always be less than or equal to the true (unknown) remaining cost `h*(n)`: `h(n) <= h*(n)` for all `n`.
- You always pop the node `n` with the minimum total cost `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)` off of `OPEN`, where `g(n)` is the cost of the path traversed so far to reach `n`.

So, suppose you just popped a node `n` off of `OPEN` which turns out to be the goal state. You know for sure (due to the second point) that *every single other node* in `OPEN` has a greater or equal total `f`-score. Because of the first point, you also know that these `f`-scores of all these other nodes in `OPEN` are not overestimates; they'll certainly not get better. They're either precisely correct, or underestimates of the cost. You know for sure they'll never outright beat `n` anymore, so the path you've just found to `n` will at least be an optimal path (it might not be the *only* optimal path though).

Comment: The claim that f values on OPEN are not going to get better is not true. That's because the heuristics considered is not consistent, only admissible. F values are not non decreasing. That's actually the point in reopening CLOSED nodes in this case.

Comment: With "not going to get better", I meant that they're "not going to get better than the `f`-score of the goal node `n`". That's still correct. `n` must by definition have `h(n) = 0`, and therefore `f(n) = g(n)`, because it already is the goal and it must have an admissible heuristic. All other nodes still in `OPEN` must have at least as large of an `f`-score, and due to the assumption of admissible heuristics those `f`-scores can't be *overestimates* either, they must be either perfectly correct or underestimates of the cost from them to the goal. They'll never be strictly better than `n`.

Comment: Note that this work because we only check whether `n` is the goal after popping it off of `OPEN` again. If we did have consistent heuristics, we could do this earlier; we could immediately trace back the path when we run into it, instead of first pushing it into `OPEN` and then waiting till we get to pop it again.

Comment: How can you immediately conclude when you run into the goal if h is consistent?

Comment: If `h` is consistent you can **1)** remove the first part inside the for-loop where you see if you've just found a more efficient path to a node that was already closed (you can just `continue` the for-loop instead if the new node already turns out to be in `CLOSED`), and **2)** in all the lines that say `put something on OPEN`, you can first check if that `something` is the goal, and immediately return the path if it indeed turns out to be the goal, instead of first pushing it to `OPEN` and then continuing till it gets popped again.

Comment: I know how to implement it(the part with the removal in the for loop), I was asking for the proof why it should work like that.

Comment: see the "Consequences of monotonicity" part [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic#Consequences_of_monotonicity)

Answer (score 1):

This question is a good one. I meet the same question. thanks to @LearningMath
The received answers is almost right, thanks to @Dennis Soemers.
But I find some mistakes from Dennis Soemers's comments , it troubles me for a long time.

> If `h` is consistent you can **1)** remove the first part inside the for-loop where you see if you've just found a more efficient path to a node that was already closed (you can just `continue` the for-loop instead if the new node already turns out to be in `CLOSED`), and **2)** in all the lines that say `put something on OPEN`, you can first check if that `something` is the goal, and immediately return the path if it indeed turns out to be the goal, instead of first pushing it to `OPEN` and then continuing till it gets popped again.

The first part is true,  but the second part is false; I won't prove this theoretically and completely, just show you a counterexample from  [CS 188 lecture pdf](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/sp19/assets/slides/lecture3.pdf) .
[image]
In the other hand, if you search standard A* pesudo code from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), you'll find that goal_check execuate after be enqueued.

Comment: you didn't answer the question. but thanks your notice.

Answer (score 1):

After reading dennis' answer, I would like to make a brief addition from my own understanding.

Let's imagine that there is another node in open_list, `f(another) >= f(n)`.
because `f(n)=g(n)+h(n)`, `n` is goal node, so `h(n) = 0`, then `f(another) >= g(n)`;

Then, let's recall admissible heuristic principle as below:

> Heuristics are still admissible, meaning that the heuristic cost `h(n)` of a node `n` must always be less than or equal to the true (unknown) remaining cost `h*(n)`: `h(n) <= h*(n)` for all `n`

Next, Let's imagine that there is path connecting `another`node and goal `n'` node,
then `f(another->n') = g(another->n') + h(n')`, and `h(n') = 0`, so `f(another->n') = g(another->n')`. No doubt `g(another->n') > g(another)`, because of positive path cost.

so we have:

```
condition:
1. g(another) + h(another) = f(another) >= f(n) = g(n);
2. f(another->n') = g(another->n') > g(another)
*important:  [admissible]
3. h(another) <= h*(another) = g(another->n') - g(another)

=>

conlusion:
f(another->n') >= f(another) >= f(n)
```

Therefore, the node `n` have already the min `f`. 
In fact, my above derivation is proof that admissible heuristic guarantees optimal. more info ref to: [Admissible heuristic - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic)

I hope I've made the issue clear for you.